# How to enable full field prefix matching in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

This query, which searches for the word `little`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "max_expansions": 20,
                "prefix_length": 3,
                "query": "little",
                "slop": 1,
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Returns the following matches

```
"title": "Little Gem"
"title": "Little Szechuan"
```

However, if I change the word to `little s`, and I am expecting `"Little Szechuan"` to match.

The following query will get zero match

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "max_expansions": 20,
                "prefix_length": 3,
                "query": "little",
                "slop": 1,
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to tweak `prefix_length` to 1, there is still no match

Here is the mapping used for `title`

```
      "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
```

Here is the analyzer used for `title`

```
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "my_snow"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_snow": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "English"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: What is your mapping for "title"?

Comment: @kcdragon please see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce this with only two documents.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "my_snow"
               ],
               "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "my_snow": {
               "type": "snowball",
               "language": "English"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/_mapping/test" -d'
{
   "test": {
      "properties": {
         "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/test/1" -d'
{
  "title": "Little Gem"
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/test/2" -d'
{
  "title": "Little Szechuan"
}'

curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/test/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "max_expansions": 20,
                "prefix_length": 3,
                "query": "little s",
                "slop": 1,
                "type": "phrase_prefix"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I'm wondering if you are running into a limitation described at the bottom of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

> Consider the query string quick brown f. This query works by creating a phrase query out of quick and brown (i.e. the term quick must exist and must be followed by the term brown). Then it looks at the sorted term dictionary to find the first 50 terms that begin with f, and adds these terms to the phrase query.

How many documents in your index/type have a title that begins with "s"? You could try increasing the max expansions which should find more terms at the cost of performance.

Comment: good point. I set my max_expansions to 50000 and managed to get the desired behaviour. Do you have a recommendation for how I should index this field differently? (instead of setting such a big max epansions)

Comment: The docs on that same page mention using the "completion suggester" but it appears that it has not been released yet. I see two options: 1. increase max_expansions if you can set it to a reasonable number, 2. don't include a "word" in the query if it has only one character. you would do this in either the application level or ES (if it is supported). the idea is a query for "little s" would act like a query for "little" but a query for "little sz" would do a query for "little sz"

Comment: @samol if this solved your question, would you mind marking it as the answer. If not, let me know what you are missing.